# How to convert a numpy array (which is actually a BGR image) to Base64 string?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, base64

I know how to convert an image in the disk to base64 via *reading* the file. However, in this instance, I already have the image as a numpy array in my program, captured via a camera, like `image[:,:,3]`. How do I convert it to base64 string such that the image can still be recovered? I tried this.

```
from base64 import b64encode    
base64.b64encode(image)
```

It does indeed gives me a string, but when I tested with https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter, it could not render the image, which means there is something wrong in the conversion. Help please.

I know a solution is to write the image into the disk as a jpg picture and then read it into a base64 string. But obviously, I don't want a file i/o when I can avoid it.

Comment: might have to do with the [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Comment: It's not clear what type of object `image` is. If it's a `PIL Image`, then you'll need to convert it to a string by calling `save` with a [BytesIO fp parameter](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save). Then you can encode the binary string as you've shown above. If `image` is a `NumPy` array, then you can create a `PIL Image` using `Image.fromarray(..)`.

Comment: image is a numpy.ndarray of dimension [:,:3] and data int64, created via openCV, directly from the camera

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example to show what you need to do:

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import base64
import numpy

# creare a random numpy array of RGB values, 0-255
arr = 255 * numpy.random.rand(20, 20, 3)

im = Image.fromarray(arr.astype("uint8"))
#im.show()  # uncomment to look at the image
rawBytes = io.BytesIO()
im.save(rawBytes, "PNG")
rawBytes.seek(0)  # return to the start of the file
print(base64.b64encode(rawBytes.read()))
```

I can paste the string printed into the [base64 image converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) and it'll look similar to `im.show()`, as the site enlarges the image.

You may need to manipulate your array or provide an appropriate [PIL mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) when creating your image

Comment: If anyone is looking for a solution using OpenCV, this solution does not generate artifacts or discoloration as the solution above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928205/python-opencv-image-to-byte-string-for-json-transfer

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more round-about from the other answers, but in case someone else lands here trying to show an image as a Qt base-64 tooltip, the other methods won't work. I had more luck using a QBuffer and QImage:

```py
# Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836998/9463643
import qimage2ndarray as q2n

buffer = QtCore.QBuffer()
buffer.open(buffer.WriteOnly)
buffer.seek(0)

img = (np.random.random((100,100))*255).astype('uint8')
img = q2n.array2qimage(img)

img.save(buffer, "PNG", quality=100)
encoded = bytes(buffer.data().toBase64()).decode() # <-- Here's the base 64 image
html = f'<img src="data:image/png;base64,{encoded}">'
element.setToolTip(html)
```